# ClosedXML Worksheet doesn't contain AddPicture function

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am creating a site in ASP.NET MVC & C# and working with ClosedXML.
Is there a way to insert an image inside a worksheet at a certain position?

I have found the code on the [ClosedXML GitHub](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/How-can-I-insert-an-image) (using the addPicture method).

However when I try to do the same I get the error:

> ClosedXML.Excel.IXLWorksheet' don't contain a definition for 'AddPicture' methode.

I'm using ClosedXML version 0.87 with .NET framework 4.5.

Comment: ClosedXML.Excel.Drawings does not exist

Comment: In the link you have provided - at the bottom it says "Ability to add picture was added in v0.88" - i.e. after the version you are using.

Comment: hola! thanks a lot, have not read that part

Answer (score 0):

Feature to add the image has been included from version 0.88 so you have to update closed XML version latest is 0.93.

If you want to learn from scratch you can refer to link.

Closed XML MVC: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxURyr2PIhCPRDEj86cj7iUHBJ29Yl_i5